# Pass php variable (on click) to another php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

Case: I'm creating buttons of sql data (while loop), for each row result(machine_id, tag_name, real_value), i create one button. This button has an onclick method which calls the javascript method "drawChart()", and pop ups a chart with a static query. I'm trying to get this query dynamic with the values of the button which is clicked.

Piece of the code which creates the buttons.

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row["int_value"] == 0 && $row["real_value"] == 0.0 && $row["bool_value"] != "") {
        $data[] = $row;
        $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td width="30%"><button name="view"  value="view" id="id" class="view_btn_data" onclick="drawChart(\'' . $row["tag_name"] . '\')">' . $row["tag_name"] . '</button></td> 
                 <td width="30%">' . $row["bool_value"] . '</td>  
                 <td width="40%">' . $row["datetime"] . '</td> 
            </tr> 
            ';
    }
```

Javascript code of drawChart():

```
function drawChart()
{
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(tagname) {

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "testChart.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {tagname: tagname},
        async: false
    }).responseText;


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Values',
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };

    //var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    //chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    $('#chartModal').modal("show");
}
```

}

Chart gets his data of testChart.php, query below:

```
 $tagname = $_REQUEST['tagname'];

 $Chart = "SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT *,
                @rn := if( @tag_name = tag_name,
                   @rn + 1,
                   if(@tag_name := tag_name, 1, 1)
                ) as tag_count
            FROM waardes 
            CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0, @tag_name := '') as vars
            ORDER BY tag_name
        ) as T          
      WHERE tag_count < 51 AND machine_id LIKE 3 AND tag_name LIKE '. $tagname .'
      ORDER BY datetime DESC";
```

It works, but with a static chart, point is, if the button is clicked, i want to pass the parameters of that $row, to the query "WHERE tag_count < 51 AND machine_id LIKE **Variable of $row["machine_id"]** AND tag_name LIKE **Variable of $row["tag_name"]**".

*Sorry if it's a bit messy, not really familair with php, html and javascript.

Comment: pass your machine id in url "testChart.php?id=".$row['machine_id'] and access it in your php page using $_GET['machine_id']

Comment: I've editted the code above.. please look again.

Answer (score 0):

The changes below will link a tagname into the drawchart() function and send it along with your ajax request.

Then just read the tagname in the PHP and build it into the MySQL query.

PHP

```
<td width="30%"><button name="view"  value="view" id="id" class="view_btn_data" onclick="drawChart(\'' . $row["tag_name"] . '\')">' . $row["tag_name"] . '</button></td>
```

JS

```
function drawChart(tagname) {

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "testChart.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data{tagname:tagname}
        async: false
    }).responseText;
```

Comment: I've 1:1 copied your code into my code, i dont see how javascript connects "tagname" with tag_name(in php file) tho. And how do i get the parameters in the query in testChart.php now? Sorry im a noob with php.

Comment: If you view the source you should see the tagname inside the onclick="drawChart() now. This gets passed to the javascript function and sent via ajax to the server.

Tagname will be in the $_REQUEST['tagname'] variable in PHP

Comment: If i understand correct: Parameters from createButtons.php -> Javascript create chart.js -> chart.php. I've got the parameters in my javascript now as you say(havent tested because i dont know how to test with netbeans), now i need the parameters in my .php file where the query is located.. Can you give me an example? Sorry 10 weeks experience with php.

Comment: I've editted the original question to the information of your answer, can you check if its right?